# Binding Command on dynamically loaded menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am successfully populating a menuitem with a list of cars. I want each car in the menuitem to be able to fire a command "RemoveCarCommand". On a dynamically loaded menuitem of cars (or anything), I know I need to have the command assigned to each car that is in the menuitem, but I cannot figure out the XAML to do that. Can someone help?

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove Car" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCars}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding RemoveCarCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over thinking your issue, if each menuitem is going to perform the same task just on a different "car", you can just point all of them to the same event handler for click then access the datacontext to find out which one was clicked and thus which car to remove.

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove Car" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCars}" click"removeCar"/>
```

in CB

```
private void removeCar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Car car = ((sender as Button).DataContext as Car);

    car.remove();
    //OR
    CarsList.Remove(car);
}
```

If you absolutely MUST use the command MVVM binding this is what you need:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameters)
    {
        _execute(parameters);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Then add this in your class obj for Car:

```
public class Car
{
    private ICommand _ClickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ClickCommand == null)
            {
                _ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Click(param, EventArgs.Empty));
            }
            return _ClickCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how you bind to it in WPF:

```
                <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
                    </Style>
                </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks and yes that would work, but I would like a MVVM solution. Sorry I did not mention that.

Comment: Can I ask why? The event handler is going to be in code behind either way, you are just changing the way the event handler is bound to the event, doing so using styles instead of just directly to click is inducing more work and application overhead than is needed, unless we are missing a peice of the puzzle.

Comment: The whole application is MVVM and I'd like to keep it that way. Binding to a command keeps you from having code behind, which makes the application easier to unit test.

Comment: Well then you really aren't going to like how you go about binding your command to the click event, you will have to create a custom ICommand that will wrap your command object in a click event handler, which is more CB, and typically even harder to unit test as the ICommand interface can do some funky stuff in stack traces.

Comment: No funky stuff needed. All of the ICommand stuff is in place I just need to get my XAML correct to correctly fire the Binding for the specific car selected. And no code behind (I believe) needed.

Comment: I updated answer with a sample ICommand wrapper that I use, but the only reason I use this is because the click command for each menu item in my case is different because they are plugin driven.

Comment: Which looks suspiciously similar to what you already have, so now you see what I mean about ICommand being tricky to debug. Are you getting any binding errors?

Comment: I just saw the MVVM code you put in. I have all that. I just need the correctly formatted XAML that will work. Something like this works if I have a hardcoded menuitem: <MenuItem Header="Remove Car" Command="{Binding RunThisCommand}" />. I want a XAML solution that works for this: <MenuItem Header="Remove Car" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableCar}" Command="{Binding RunThisCommand}" />. The Command binding does not work when you dynamically populate a menuitem, but I'm sure there is a way, I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: I think I see the issue, you are applying the style to the menuitem ItemContainerStyle, try moving the style to the actual `Menu.ItemContainerStyle`. It will work if your ICommand is set up properly as that's exactly what I use it for, dynamically generated menus built from plugins that need click handlers.

Comment: I am using menuitem ItemContainerStyle because there are some items in the menu that are hard coded. Just this piece of the menu needed to be generated at run time. I'll try it though because since I'm the one asking for help, I do not know how to get it to work anyway :)

Comment: Remebber, ItemContainerStyle applies to children and not itself. If there are menu items that are hard coded, they won't have a binding and thus a ClickCommand so it won't harm anything. If that does not solve I would venture a guess that it is you class that uses the ICommand or the binding object itself at fault and not your MVVM.

Comment: Well, that did not work and I cannot see any other way to get the binding to work, so I will go with the click event for now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Post your CB into the ques, lets look at that, i'm sure the binding is working because its pretty straight forward, unless your relative source is outta wack, in such case post the rest of the XAML aswell. Aren't you glad you want with the easier to test MVVM method lol.

Comment: There is no code behind yet. I am adding that now. Code behind is easy enough...I can do that. If I run into any trouble, I'll start a new thread. Thanks.

Comment: Well you need it to implement ICommand, that may be why it isn't working lol, command binding is not as easy as mapping the command prop to a action prop, it absolutely requires code behind. The `RelayCommand` class is my ans is an example of what you need.

Comment: Ugh.  All he needs is to pass the car to delete to a command defined on the view model containing the list of cars.  `{Binding DataContext.RemoveCar, ElementName=parentElement}` (hate relative bindings).  Then just pass in the car to the command parameter.  `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`. Now the view model can simply call `.Remove(parameter as Car)`.  Done and done.

Comment: You dont need the command parameter since the binding object is already known, the rest he is already doing which is why the rest of the code needs to be seen.